# Postgres: Returning first 3 characters of a JSON property

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

```
id | foo
--------
1  | {'source': 'england'}
```

I'm using `foo -> 'source'` to pull the data, but what I want to only get the first 3 characters of the source.

I would normally use `LEFT(columnName, 3)` but this function only works when the value is a string.

So I cannot do

```
foo -> LEFT('source', 3) as source
```

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`->`  results in `JSON`

`->>` results in `TEXT`

So,use this

```
select LEFT(foo ->>'source' , 3) from t;
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=09b7a573fb104a4c996a2f23c0076c0a)